# Integral of a Recursive Function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion, symbolic-math, integral

I want to compute the following symbolic integral which is recursive :

```
function [y] = myfunc(i,T) 
    s = sym('s');
    x= sym('x');
    h=[....]  %matrix n*n (function of x)
    d=[....]  %matrix n*1 (constants)
    for k=1:n
        if (T>0)
           y= int(exp(-s*x)*h(i,k)*myfunc(k,T-x/d(i)),'x',0,T); 
    end
end
```

I expected MATLAB, while computing the integral, calls `myfunc(k,T-x/d(i))` for different values of 'x' from 0 to T. However, it returns error since `myfunc` would be called with symbolic value 'x' and not the real value. Indeed, it cannot determine `if (T>0)` expression is true or false.

I would be thankful if you can suggest how this recursive integral can be computed ?. Thanks

Comment: I dont think I'll be able to help you, but from trying to understand your problem, it is still unclear to me what 'h' and 'd' contains. Also, in the recursive scheme, why does not 'i' change as you pass the function along?

Comment: I wrote the first code simple and small to only focus on the question .But as you asked, I edited and added more details to it. Also, the elements of 'h' are probability density functions that are function of 'x' and 'd' contains constant values ...thanks

Comment: Symbolic integration does not (cannot) work by calling `myfunc` recursively with different values. That approach only works for numerical quadrature (which, obviously, only approximates the integral, though usually very well).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that a different real value is used in each step of a recursive function, you can define a variable to account for how deep you are.

Suppose we call it `depth`, and on the top level it is equal to 1. Each time you go one step deeper you increase `depth` by 1.

Now, if you want to get a number corresponding to the right depth, you can just call it as `y(depth)`.